# Why RememberMeAuthenticationFilter does not redirect to requested url?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm new in Spring Security and I'm sorry for my English.
I have a rememberme cookie and when the request comes to the filter RememberMeAuthenticationFilter - it makes authentication, breaks the next processing and immediately returns to user only 200 status with defaultUrl, something like

> {"redirectTo":"/","success":true,"username":"userName","roles":[listOfRoles]}

in here

```
public RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
        RememberMeServices rememberMeServices) {

   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    ...
    if (successHandler != null) {   // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<In here the request breaks.
                            successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response,
                                    rememberMeAuth);

                            return;
                        }
    ...
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Tell me please how to do next: the request goes down throw the filter after successful authentication with rememberme cookie to chain.doFilter(request, response);
And after all filters go to controller method which user asks.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, if somebody interesting. The solution was not to inject authenticationSuccessHandler to RememberMeAuthenticationFilter. I redefined the bean  RememberMeAuthenticationFilter (thats by default defined inside grails) and not inject authenticationSuccessHandler. And thats why this code not processing and go to chain.doFilter.